# What are the downside of a super-quick fermentation?

Tags: fermentation

As it can be seen in this Q/A many beginner brewers observe a bloomed fermentation, excessive for one day, then no sign of fermentation but by measuring the gravity.

I recently got this problem for a german style wheatbeer. The beer itself ended-up quite nice.

What would be the known downside in term of beer quality from such a fermentation, if any?

Comment: What was your pitch size and fermentation temperature? Speed itself will not matter all that much, but reasons for slow or fast fermentation will.

Comment: For 24 litres with a yeast optimal for 20 to 24 Celsius. I put the yeast at 24° and it reached 25°/26° pretty quickly while outside temperature was around 20°. Then it dropped to 18° 3 days later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually a fermentation happens quicker than normal for 3 reasons. Poor oxygen, large yeast pitch, warm temperatures.

**Low Disolved Oxygen**: Yeast needs oxygen in wort to multiply. When oxygen is gone it's one of the triggers for yeast to move from growth phase to feeding phase. *This can result in off flavors and mostly poor attenuation, incomplete fermentation*

**Large Pitch**: Beer styles that have clean ester profiles do very well with large pitch rates, even full pitch by using the entire cake or trub from a like batch.  Most esters are made during yeast growth, with larger pitches the growth phase is short or skipped all together greatly reducing growth esters. *This can be bad for styles that are ester dependant like belgians, saisons etc*

**Warm Temperatures** The warmer the temperature the higher the metabolism of the yeast. Everything happens quicker. *In this haste a lot of undesirable chemicals are produced. Bad esters and larger molecule alcohols. Leaving a beer hot from fusal alcohols and even have extremes of nail polish aromas.*

Hope this helps.